# When using Basic Scaling, how does Google App Engine decide when to scale up?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to understand what determines when App Engine creates a **second** instance. In other words, when is the first instance considered too busy to handle a request.

According to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types):

> Basic scaling creates instances when your application receives requests.

And

> Multiple basic scaling instances are only started as necessary, in order to handle increased traffic.

That explains when the first instance is created but not when subsequent instances are created (what counts as "increased traffic"?)

What I see is that with the following `app.yaml` configuration:

```yaml
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 2
  idle_timeout: 2m
```

Only one instance is created, even when long-running requests completely block the instance, causing some requests to fail with HTTP 503 and "Request was aborted after waiting too long to attempt to service your request."

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you read this section? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/how-instances-are-managed#startup

Comment: I did. It says "Multiple basic scaling instances are only started as necessary, in order to handle increased traffic" which is still vague. What counts as "increased traffic"?

Comment: Have you checked [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/xkDuAWMpEBQ) and can you share your complete `app.yaml` file?